# C++ programatically obtain the display number?

Tags: c++, windows, api, indexing, monitor

I'm attempting to write a program that involves activating/deactivating monitors.

I currently am using calls to [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx) to do a lot of this work.

However, EnumDisplayDevices uses an index (called iDevNum in the documentation) to determine which display you're talking about.

These indices however can change whenever monitors are activated or deactivated.

For example, if we have 2 displays connected and we disconnect the one at index 0, then the second display (which was originally index 1) now becomes index 0.

This isn't immediately obvious when looking at the control panel window for screen resolution however, as each monitor has a number that appears to stay with them regardless of which display index they are.

For example, if we follow the above example of deactivating monitor 1 which has index 0, the control panel will still show the second monitor with number 2, although EnumDisplayDevices accesses it with index 0.

Thus, I'm wondering if there is a way to get these more consistent IDs for displays?  Or if not, is there a way to make windows not automatically rearrange the list of displays so that if you disconnect index 0, index 0 stays disconnected and it doesn't automatically shift index 1 down?